# VC2019 Web API not allows .NET CORE 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've installed the .NET 5.0 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

After that, in the powershell I've runned the dotnet --version and get the result: 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6

My VS2019 Community is in Version 16.7.1

When I try to start a new ASP.NET Core Web Application I can't choose the ASP.NET Core 5.0

[image]

I even tried to change in the csproj settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But I still get the error message:

```
NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 5.0.  Either target .NET Core 3.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 5.0.
```

I've tried everything I could to install and use ASP.NET WEB API with Preview 5.0 but I coulnd't run!

Comment: Do you have the Preview SDKs option enabled? Probably not. Search the settings for "Preview".

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, now it's working!